# AMD Radeon RX 6700 XT Red Devil - broken driver?

Tags: 20.04

I have a newly built PC with an AMD Radeon RX 6700 XT Red Devil GPU and a MSI AMD Ryzen MEG X570 ACE AM4 motherboard. If I try to install Ubuntu 20.04 with default option (the first entry on the install menu), the system appears to freeze completely, but I can install in 'safe graphics mode'. However, when I reboot after that, the system simply freezes.

My suspicion is that whichever driver Ubuntu installs, is broken, or certainly not a match for the GPU. Is there any way to get Ubuntu 20.04 to simply install the driver it used in safe graphics mode?

***Edit***

I found I can install Ubuntu 20.04 server version, and it boots up without a problem. I can probably get away with now installing a desktop environment, and then the driver from Radeon's website; perhaps that will work.

Comment: No, not broken and the only driver for your graphics card - `amdgpu` - is the correct one. What you should do before anything else is update UEFI. Troubleshoot from there, it may need some changes in the UEFI settings, defaults are designed for Windows, as usual.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with EUFI - what should I look out for?

Comment: @ChanganAuto actually, I tried to boot with a different GPU, and it starts up fine, so it definietly seems to get past UEFI well enough.

Comment: You should update it anyway. UEFI is that firmware that replcaed BIOS more than 10 years ago, get used to it. Check MSI for updates and also download and read the full user's manual, familiarize yourself with all the relevant firmware settings.